# How to compare time stamps from consecutive rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that I would like to sort by a timestamp desc and then compare all consecutive rows to determine the difference between each row.  From there, I would like to find all the rows whose difference is greater than ~2hours.

I'm stuck on how to actually compare consecutive rows in a table.  Any help would be much appreciated.

I'm using Oracle SQL Developer 3.2

Comment: I re-tagged the question with `oracle` assuming that you are using Oracle's SQL tool with their own database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't show us your table definition, but something like this:

```
select *
from (
   select t.*, 
          t.timestamp_column, 
          t.timestamp_column - lag(timestamp_column) over (order by timestamp_column) as diff
    from the_table t
) x
where diff > interval '2' hour;
```

This assumes that `timestamp_column` is defined as `timestamp` not `date` (otherwise the result of the difference wouldn't be an `interval`)